# Python- Lists of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.3

I have to create a code of lists of lists where it returns "True" exactly when there exists(at least 1) and favorite band in all of the lists(may be > 3). I'm very new to programming and I am very lost on what to do. I have tried something, but it's not completely filled in. I need some help!

```
favoriteBandLists = [
    ["Metallica","Linkin Park","Alice In Chains","Nirvana", "Soundgarden"],
    ["Pink Floyd","Alice In Chains","Soundgarden","Metallica","Linkin Park"],
    ["Audioslave","Offspring","Soundgarden","Linkin Park","The Beatles"]]
```

My Code:

```
def commonFavoriteBand(list):
    foundCounterExampleyet = False
    for i in range(()):
        if(()):
            foundCounterExampleYet = True
    return not(foundCounterExampleYet)

print (commonFavoriteBand())

def commonFavoriteBandA():
    foundExampleYet = False
    for value in values:
        if():
            foundExampleYet = True

return foundExampleYet
```

Comment: can you double check the indentation on your posted code?  it's very difficult to see what's going on there..

Comment: @msturdy is there a specific way to indent it? I apologize I'm kind of new on here

Comment: copy your code into the box, select it and then Ctrl+k

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the simplest but most comprehensible way is this:

```
favorite_band_lists = [
    ["Metallica", "Linkin Park", "Alice In Chains", "Nirvana", "Soundgarden"],
    ["Pink Floyd", "Alice In Chains", "Soundgarden", "Metallica", "Linkin Park"],
    ["Audioslave", "Offspring", "Soundgarden", "Linkin Park", "The Beatles"],
]

def common_favorite_band(band_lists):
    # If there are no bands at all, you can't really say there are any in
    # common
    if not band_lists:
        return False

    # Convert the first band list to a "set" -- a group of unique items
    common_bands = set(band_lists[0])

    # Then, for every other band list...
    for bands in band_lists[1:]:
        # ...intersect it with the running set.  This means `common_bands`
        # should throw away anything that isn't also in `bands`.
        common_bands.intersection_update(bands)

    # Now common_bands contains only the bands that are in every list.
    # But you wanted True or False, so cast it to a bool -- an empty set
    # will become False, a set with at least one item will become True.
    return bool(common_bands)

print(common_favorite_band(favorite_band_lists))  # True!
```

(btw, function and variable names are traditionally written in snake_case in Python, not camelCase)

Comment: when I run it, it says "band_lists" is not defined?

Comment: did you make a typo...?  it ran fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
s=set(favorite_band_lists[0])
for ii in favorite_band_lists[1:]:
    s=s.intersection(s,ii)
    if len(s) == 0:
        break
```

This will stop as soon as an intersection is empty, which may be desirable. It also returns the bands that are common across lists, if any. To produce `True` or `False`, check if the length of s -- the intersection list -- is > 0.

```
print len(s) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different solution to the others:

```
def common_favorite_band(band_lists):
    for band in band_lists[0]:
        count = 0
        for band_list in band_lists[1:]:
            if band  not in band_list:
                break
            else:
                count += 1
        if count == len(band_lists) - 1:
            return True
    return False
```

It looks at all the bands in the first list and checks if that band is in each other list. We add 1 to count every time it is. For any band, if count reaches the length of band_lists - 1, then we may return True and finish. If at any time a band does not appear in another list, we break from that iteration of the loop and try another band. If we have checked every band and we have not got a count equal to the length of band_list - 1, then we return False.